# Install different rom on Chinese made android phone

Tags: rom

Recently I bought a Chinese made android phone. Specifications of the phone is given [here](http://symphony-mobile.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=63&product_id=143). The phone has mediatek mtk6577 processor. I been thinking to install different ROM in my device. But, I can not find source to download this ROM. Is it possible to install google stock rom in this phone and where can I find this rom? How do I know which rom is compatible with my device?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See also: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/16575). And no, you cannot simply use a "Google stock ROM", as that misses the drivers for special hardware your device most likely contains, which then could not work.

Answer (score 1):

First step is finding out the OEM (manufacturer) of your handset.

Coincidentally, the specs and body closely resembles that of [Cherry Mobile Titan](http://www.ilonggotechblog.com/2012/10/cherry-mobile-w500-titan-price-specs.html#.UTl_9uSUHI8) compared to [yours](http://www.muthofon.com/phonespecification/symphony-w90-2692.php).

This is the [original version](http://www.gsmarena.com/spice_mi_500_stellar_horizon-5052.php). There is only a guide on how to root [here](http://www.droidiser.com/2012/10/spice-mi500-clockworkmod-guide.html). Can see no custom ROM available as of now/

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me where can I keep my eye to find out about custom rom release?

Comment: I can lead you to symbianize and tipidcp that discusses these phones but unfortunately its in tagalog. If you want to, a dump of Titan's ROM can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzwEEgpbLRvdOUJnQXI0SUxmMTA/edit?pli=1). You need root and CWM first to install it. Default language is English and has Cherry mobiles bloatware. [Source](http://askhideki.com/cherry-mobile-titan-5-point-multi-touch-update-how-to/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bunch of resources for Symphony phones:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2060290

Your phone is specifically mentioned so it should work fine, but make sure you're careful!